# C++ Template : Choosing overloaded functions using implicit conversion to template instantiated type!

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

Consider these overloaded functions,

```
void fun(Int2Type<1>) {}
void fun(Int2Type<2>) {}
void fun(Int2Type<3>) {}
void fun(Int2Type<4>) {}
```

I want to call these in this way,

```
fun(1); // this should call first function
fun(4); // this should call fourth function
```

Is there a way to do that? If yes, so can we do the same with some runtime value, say this,
*(please note that in the above calls, the argument is known at compile-time)*

```
fun(value); // value can be decided at runtime!
```

---

Or any alternative if that is not possible? The goal is, different function should be called based on different integral value!

---

## EDIT

By the way, I cannot use any of the following:

1. Using `switch(value)`
2. using some `SomeFuncTable funTable[] = {fun(Int2Type<1>(), fun(Int2Type<2>()}` etc

Comment: I sincerely doubt this is possible but would love to know the answer if one does indeed exist.

Comment: You didn't mentioned that Int2Type comes from Loki.

Comment: @nice blonde stupid girl :Yeah I didn't mention it, so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it a little differently:

```
template<int N> void func();
template<> void func<1>(){/*the body*/}
template<> void func<2>(){/*the body*/}
```

And then you may call: `func<1>()`.

Or you may call the original code this way: `func(Int2Type<1>())`.

Anyway all of this only works with compile time constants.

Comment: I think that is good to experiment with. Let me reach   home, I need to play with all these. Thanks for the post. :-)

Comment: Actually the whole purpose of [Int2Type](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/html/a00683.html) is to create a **distinct type** from an **int** in order to dispatch a call to different overloads.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no way to use runtime values as a template parameter. The only thing you can do is something like:

```
void fun(int x) {
    switch(x) {
    case 1:
        fun(Int2Type<1>());
        break;
    case 2:
        fun(Int2Type<2>());
        break;
    case 3:
        fun(Int2Type<3>());
        break;
    case 4:
        fun(Int2Type<4>());
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to accomplish what you want, because they all boil down to the same thing- a jump table, or a large series of if/else. That's it. Any other feature is going to become just that. Just make a jump table. You could use an array of function pointers (the fastest) or something more flexible like an `unordered_map<int, std::function<void()>>`.

Oh, unless you want to write your own JIT compiler and JIT the new assembly code when you need it. You could do that. But I don't really see the point, as you still run down to the same problem- how to pick the code path to take, which is going to become a jump table or if/else chain.